# Windows Fall Creator - can't install using node npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

After installing Windows Fall Creator version 1709 I cannot install anything using npm. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling node. It appears to be a permissions issue. Whenever I try I get

```
ENOENT
o -4058
all rename
nt ENOENT:
```

I've tried running using Windows bash and it too errors out with nearly the same message. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webroot Secure anywhere was broken with Fall Creators and prevented node from running.

See https://community.webroot.com/t5/Product-Releases/Windows-10-Fall-Creator-Update-Bug-Fix/td-p/305469

Comment: https://community.webroot.com/t5/Product-Releases/Windows-10-Fall-Creator-Update-Bug-Fix/td-p/305469

Answer (score 0):

If it worked before the Fall Creators update, you might just need to update npm and try whatever you wanted to do again.

```
npm i -g npm
```

Another thing you might want to try is clearing your package cache with the following command, that sometimes can cause issues on Windows too.

```
npm cache clear
// or optionally even
npm cache clear -f
```

Comment: Nothing worked. I had to fall back from that update. It seemed to have something to do with the file system and permissions on the files nom was trying to create.